# How to get the unique row value and return boolean result in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Table     A    B    C    
Round     0.2  0    1     
Triangle  3    3    3     
Penta     1    1    1
```

I wish to get the result like below:

Which mean if the unique value for column A to C is result in only one value then return false, if more than one return true. In conclusion, if the value for column A is equal to B and equal to C, then return false.

```
Table     A    B    C    Result
Round     0.2  0    1     True
Triangle  3    3    3     False
Penta     1    1    1     False
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare last 3 columns by last column with not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (`!=`) and then add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per rows:

```
print (df)
      Table    A  B  C  Result
0     Round  0.2  0  1    True
1  Triangle  3.0  3  3   False
2     Penta  1.0  1  1   False

df['Result'] = df.iloc[:, -3:].ne(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0).any(axis=1)
print (df)
      Table    A  B  C  Result
0     Round  0.2  0  1    True
1  Triangle  3.0  3  3   False
2     Penta  1.0  1  1   False
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.iloc[:, -3:].ne(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0))
       A      B      C
0   True   True  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

If first column is index, solution is simplify and is possible compare all columns with any column:

```
df['Result'] = df.ne(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0).any(axis=1)

print (df)
            A  B  C  Result
Table                      
Round     0.2  0  1    True
Triangle  3.0  3  3   False
Penta     1.0  1  1   False
```

Comment: why `df.iloc[:, -1]`

Comment: @pyd - It is last column, give me a sec for explanation

Comment: @pyd - Thank you.